# Adding columns to xts object: strange results

Tags: r, xts

I was trying to add some columns of TAs to an existing xts object but end up with some bizarre results. Here is a sample code:

```
getSymbols("SPY")
names(SPY) <- c("open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "adj")
cci <- CCI(SPY[,c("high", "low", "close")])
smi <- SMI(SPY[,c("high", "low", "close")])

SPY$cci <- cci$cci
SPY$smi <- smi$smi
SPY$smisig <- smi$signal
```

The output is as follows:

```
> head(spy)
             open   high    low  close   volume    adj smi smisig
2007-01-03 142.25 142.86 140.57 141.37 94807600 120.92  NA     NA
2007-01-04 141.23 142.05 140.61 141.67 69620600 121.17  NA     NA
2007-01-05 141.33 141.40 140.38 140.54 76645300 120.21  NA     NA
2007-01-08 140.82 141.41 140.25 141.19 71655000 120.76  NA     NA
2007-01-09 141.31 141.60 140.40 141.07 75680100 120.66  NA     NA
2007-01-10 140.58 141.57 140.30 141.54 72428000 121.06  NA     NA
```

The cci column seems missing. Actually, the value of the so-called smi column is indeed cci. I feel it might be a bug in xts. On the other hand, the result would be correct if use "merge" to bind all xts objects together.

I encountered this first on R 3.0.2, then upgrade to 3.1.1. Had the same issue on both versions.
Anyone can shred some light on it? Thanks!

Comment: Look at `tail(SPY)`.  A certain number of rows are required to calculate the first value.

Comment: `smi$smi` is `NULL`, which changes the name of the last column for some reason. You meant `SPY$smi <- smi$SMI`.

Comment: The tail(SPY) seems fine. Yes, multiple rows are needed to calculated either CCI or SMI values: that's why the intial rows of both CCI and SMI are NAs.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, thanks for pointing it out... you're right. It prompts me to ask whether you can change the behavior of assigning NULL to a column for xts? The expected behavior would be deleting the column rather than renaming the last column. Thanks again!

Comment: That's an edge-case bug in zoo. I should have it patched on R-Forge today.

Comment: +1, but voting to close. Thanks for the reproducible example, but this is unlikely to help future visitors.